# Android TV application is not passing review

Tags: android, google-play, android-tv, google-play-console, leanback

I am trying to publish an app for Android TV, but it does not pass the review and gets published only for regular mobiles. Here is the manifest file, what am I doing wrong ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="PACKAGE_NAME"
android:installLocation="auto">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"></uses-feature>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.gamepad" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:name="com.app.tv.AppApliaction"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/tvapp"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/tvapp"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    android:banner="@drawable/tvapp_baner">
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.tv.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And here is the theme which I have used:

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:color">@android:color/white</item>

</style>
```

Have tried to republish does not work. Have read the whole documentation and the guide but was not able to find any conflicts with my code.

Comment: You might have received email from Google about certification failure and some info related to issues with the submission

Comment: I have the same issue wherein the app is live, but TV devices have failed. There is no Email from Google as well. All the google policies have been adhered to.
Does anyone know the way ahead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your theme to use `Leanback` Theme 
eg

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Leanback">
```

Your manifest file should have the following lines

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
```

[reference documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start)

Did you receive any email from Google regarding certification failure